# Environment with delayed expansion

Tags: environments, expansion

I'm trying to define an environment `test` that stores its contents unexpanded in a macro `\testcontents`.

For example, the code

```
\newcommand{\cmd}{bad}

\begin{test}
\cmd
\end{test}

\renewcommand{\cmd}{okay}

\testcontents
```

should print out "okay".

How would I define such an environment? I know that the environ package could be used to store the contents after expansion, but I need them unexpanded.

Comment: environ doesn't expand the body as far as I can see?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`environ` works as you require, it collects the body without expansion, the following typesets `okay`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}


\NewEnviron{test}
{\global\let\testcontents\BODY}

\begin{document}


\newcommand{\cmd}{bad}

\begin{test}
\cmd
\end{test}

\renewcommand{\cmd}{okay}

\testcontents

\end{document}
```